# ajax call result issue occurring

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with `USERID`,`USERNAME`,`SALARY` in a database.

These records are displaying in an HTML table where `USERID` comes from the table and `USERNAME` and `SALARY` will be entered by the user in `textbox`.

Here, on each on change of text box, ajax is calling and it will check whether `USERNAME / SALARY` present in the database for `USERID` (record for which USERNAME /SALARY is added) ? If return yes, then it will fire edit query else it will fire insert query.

Now, what is happening is as soon as record is added to textbox, ajax is calling and it is checking and this process is so fast that another ajax is calling before one has completed its process and so checking query returning false.

My ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
 type:'post',
 url: url,
 data :{uid:uid,rec:rec,sal:sal},
 success:function(data) {
 console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Anything that has to wait for the AJAX call to finish should be done in the `success` function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `async :false` to your ajax statement,so it will be like :

```
$.ajax({

type:'post',

url: url,

data :{uid:uid,rec:rec,sal:sal},

async : false,

success:function(data) {console.log(data);}

});
```

Comment: Please don't recommend synchronous AJAX. It's deprecated and will cause warnings in the console.

Comment: I am using async:false to overcome for this issue and it is working without any console error.

Not sure,whether version issue or like that

Comment: The warning comes from the browser, so it depends on which browser you're using. But `async: false` is generally a bad idea, it blocks the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changebox(curval,a)
{
    alert(curval);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:"id="+curval,
        url:"<?php echo site_url('contrlloer_name/function_name');?>",
        success: function(html){
            $('#'+a).html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that needs to wait for the first AJAX call to complete in the `success` function of the AJAX call. You can perform additional AJAX calls here.